# Checking for key in object and adding new keys after comparison

Tags: javascript

This is probably a repeated question but I'm having trouble with the second part of it.

I have

```
 var x = {2000: 3, 2001: 3, 2003: 2, 2006: 1, 2007: 1, 2008: 1, 2010: 1, 2012: 1, 2014: 2}
 var y = ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007, "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"]
```

Here's what I want to do.

First, check what `y` doesn't exist in `x`, taking the implicit year value as the one to compare.

Then, for each difference (you can see, for instance, 2002, 2004 or 2005 don't exist in `x`), I want to add the missing year to `x`, with a key of `0`.

Comment: @sarthakupadhyay Thanks friend. I'm sorry for that. I have researched the problem and I'm not looking to pass the buck. I saw a number of versions using `for in` but just checking for the values is not the real problem for me. The trouble is comparing and adding the remaining ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop thru your `y` variable and check if `x[key]` is `undefined`. If it is, assign 0.

```js
var x = {2000: 3, 2001: 3, 2003: 2, 2006: 1, 2007: 1, 2008: 1, 2010: 1, 2012: 1, 2014: 2};
var y = ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"]

y.forEach(v=>{
    if ( x[ v ] === undefined ) x[ v ] = 0;
});
 
console.log( x );
```

Or you can make it shorter as

```js
var x = {2000: 3, 2001: 3, 2003: 2, 2006: 1, 2007: 1, 2008: 1, 2010: 1, 2012: 1, 2014: 2};
var y = ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"]

y.forEach(v => x[v] = x[v] || 0);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: That is absolutely perfect. I knew I needed a forEach but I really didn't know you could just use simple equals and shortcuts like `v`. Thank you.